# Import all tables from PDF or html to R

Tags: r, rvest, tabulizer

I am trying to import tables from a website to R. The data is shown in [the html](https://fie.org/competitions/2022/152) as well as [a downloadable PDF](https://fie.org/competition/2022/152/results/pools/pdf?lang=en).

I have tried using the `tabulizer` package on the PDF, specifically the `expand_tables()` and `extract_areas()` functions, and they both failed for different reasons. `extract_tables()` only extracted the first table of each page, and `extract_areas()` would put each page as a single list item or dataframe in a very bad formatting. A list of the tables is a good idea, but then each table would have to be a separate list item...

I've also attempted to adapt the sollution proposed [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092329/extract-table-from-webpage-using-r) with `rvest` but for some reason, the website imports as blank, so I don't know how to import the table.

The goal is to have the tables stored separately (not to combine them) – the list idea sounds very efficient for that, but I could be wrong – in code generalizable to other websites or PDFs (they hold the same data so it doesn't make a difference).

Comment: Also, not clear what final result should be. Would you bring in the competition. place, date, referees and pool number for example?

Comment: You can extract the data from a script tag but will need to write the logic to handle initially as JSON then convert into list of tables. `data <- stringr::str_match(read_html("https://fie.org/competitions/2022/152") %>% html_text() , 'window\\._pools = (.*?);')[1,][2] %>% jsonlite::parse_json() %>% .$pools`

Comment: Strictly speaking only the pool results (and athletes) are necessary, but your solution is great! It's easy to get everything I need from that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the tables of the PDF file with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

#############################################
#### Step 1 : SaVe wikipedia page as PDF ####
#############################################

path_PDF <- "C:\\Stackoverflow84.pdf"
path_Word <- "C:\\Stackoverflow84.docx"

################################################################
#### Step 2 : Convert PDF to word document with OCR of Word ####
################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

######################################################
#### Step 3 : Highlight keywords in word document ####
######################################################
nb_Tables <- doc$tables()$count()
list_Table <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Tables)
{
  print(l)
  nb_Row <- doc$tables(l)$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- doc$tables(l)$Columns()$Count()
  mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
  {
    for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
    {
      mat_Temp[i, j] <- doc$tables(l)$cell(i, j)$range()$text()
    }
  }
  
  list_Table[[l]] <- mat_Temp
}

list_Table

[[1]]
     [,1]                    [,2]          [,3]             [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    
[1,] "GRAND PRIX\rNUOMA\r\a" "Orléans\r\a" "2021-11-12\r\a" "S\r\a" "S\r\a" "F\r\a" "I\r\a" "GP\r\a"

[[2]]
     [,1]      [,2]                          [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] "RUS\r\a" "DROZD Dariya\r\a"            "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "USA\r\a" "LINDER Kara\r\a"             "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "VEN\r\a" "CONTRERAS Patricia\r\a"      "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[4,] "ROU\r\a" "IACOB Emma\r\a"              "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ESP\r\a" "MARTIN-PORTUGUES\rLucia\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "HUN\r\a" "ZAHONYI Petra\r\a"           "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"   
[7,] "FRA\r\a" "RIBEIRO Ilona\r\a"           "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
     [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "D/4\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "17\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[2,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "23\r\a" "-2\r\a" 
[3,] "D/2\r\a" "0.17\r\a" "12\r\a" "26\r\a" "-14\r\a"
[4,] "D/2\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "17\r\a" "27\r\a" "-10\r\a"
[5,] "V/5\r\a" "1\r\a"    "30\r\a" "12\r\a" "18\r\a" 
[6,] "V/5\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "23\r\a" "24\r\a" "-1\r\a" 
[7,] "\r\a"    "0.5\r\a"  "24\r\a" "23\r\a" "1\r\a"  

[[3]]
     [,1]      [,2]                      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "FRA\r\a" "GIMALAC Margaux\r\a"     "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "ESP\r\a" "VENTURA Maria\r\a"       "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[3,] "JPN\r\a" "SASAKI Haruna\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[4,] "KOR\r\a" "KIM Jeongmi\r\a"         "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[5,] "GER\r\a" "SCHILLINGER Ylvi\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[6,] "ITA\r\a" "LUCARINI Lucia\r\a"      "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "GRE\r\a" "GEORGIADOU\rDespina\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.5\r\a"  "18\r\a" "22\r\a" "-4\r\a" 
[2,] "0.17\r\a" "14\r\a" "27\r\a" "-13\r\a"
[3,] "0.5\r\a"  "23\r\a" "22\r\a" "1\r\a"  
[4,] "0.67\r\a" "27\r\a" "11\r\a" "16\r\a" 
[5,] "0\r\a"    "11\r\a" "30\r\a" "-19\r\a"
[6,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "22\r\a" "7\r\a"  
[7,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "17\r\a" "12\r\a" 

[[4]]
     [,1]      [,2]                  [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "FRA\r\a" "SIMONS Pauline\r\a"  "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "ALG\r\a" "BENCHEKOR Naila\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "KOR\r\a" "JEON Hayoung\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "RUS\r\a" "MOSEYKO Alina\r\a"   "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ITA\r\a" "VIALE Mariella\r\a"  "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[6,] "ESP\r\a" "NAVARRO Araceli\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "GBR\r\a" "DAYKIN Kate\r\a"     "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "27\r\a" "-5\r\a" 
[2,] "0.17\r\a" "9\r\a"  "27\r\a" "-18\r\a"
[3,] "0.67\r\a" "24\r\a" "21\r\a" "3\r\a"  
[4,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "13\r\a" "16\r\a" 
[5,] "0.67\r\a" "23\r\a" "19\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[6,] "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "17\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[7,] "0.17\r\a" "17\r\a" "25\r\a" "-8\r\a" 

[[5]]
     [,1]      [,2]                         [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] "USA\r\a" "JOHNSON Honor\r\a"          "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "UKR\r\a" "KOMASHCHUK Alina\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[3,] "BUL\r\a" "HRAMOVA Olga A.\r\a"        "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "KOR\r\a" "LEE Rajin\r\a"              "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "GER\r\a" "WEBER Christine\r\a"        "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a"
[6,] "FRA\r\a" "COUDERC Annah\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
[7,] "RUS\r\a" "SHOROKHOVA\rAnastasiya\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
     [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "23\r\a" "-2\r\a" 
[2,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "22\r\a" "18\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[3,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "26\r\a" "20\r\a" "6\r\a"  
[4,] "D/4\r\a" "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "21\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[5,] "D/2\r\a" "0.17\r\a" "10\r\a" "28\r\a" "-18\r\a"
[6,] "D/2\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "22\r\a" "19\r\a" "3\r\a"  
[7,] "\r\a"    "0.5\r\a"  "22\r\a" "23\r\a" "-1\r\a" 

[[6]]
     [,1]      [,2]                     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "ESP\r\a" "MONTOYA Paula\r\a"      "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[2,] "RUS\r\a" "KLIUCHNIKOVA Alina\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "HUN\r\a" "KATONA Renata\r\a"      "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "JPN\r\a" "WAKITA Jumi\r\a"        "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ALG\r\a" "BENADOUDA Chaima\r\a"   "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "FRA\r\a" "KLEIN Louise\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a"
[7,] "GEO\r\a" "JIJIEISHVILI Lika\r\a"  "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.33\r\a" "21\r\a" "23\r\a" "-2\r\a" 
[2,] "0.83\r\a" "27\r\a" "19\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "20\r\a" "24\r\a" "-4\r\a" 
[4,] "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "20\r\a" "5\r\a"  
[5,] "0.17\r\a" "16\r\a" "29\r\a" "-13\r\a"
[6,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "19\r\a" "10\r\a" 
[7,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "26\r\a" "-4\r\a" 

[[7]]
     [,1]      [,2]                        [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "GBR\r\a" "CHART Maria\r\a"           "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[2,] "USA\r\a" "FOX-GITOMER Chloe\r\a"     "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[3,] "VEN\r\a" "RODRIGUEZ Shia\r\a"        "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[4,] "ITA\r\a" "CIARAGLIA Sofia\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "GER\r\a" "DERKUM Liska\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[6,] "HUN\r\a" "BEVIZ Dorottya\r\a"        "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a"
[7,] "FRA\r\a" "ESSOMBA MBEGA\rLorina\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.33\r\a" "18\r\a" "25\r\a" "-7\r\a" 
[2,] "0.33\r\a" "20\r\a" "24\r\a" "-4\r\a" 
[3,] "0.5\r\a"  "24\r\a" "18\r\a" "6\r\a"  
[4,] "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "21\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[5,] "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "15\r\a" "10\r\a" 
[6,] "0.17\r\a" "12\r\a" "29\r\a" "-17\r\a"
[7,] "0.83\r\a" "27\r\a" "19\r\a" "8\r\a"  

[[8]]
     [,1]      [,2]                        [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "TUR\r\a" "SHCHUKLA Iryna\r\a"        "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "USA\r\a" "MILLER Sky\r\a"            "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[3,] "RUS\r\a" "MIKHAILOVA Alina\r\a"      "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[4,] "HUN\r\a" "FENYOSI Zita\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[5,] "JPN\r\a" "TAKASHIMA Risa\r\a"        "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "FRA\r\a" "TRANQUILLE Lola\r\a"       "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "UKR\r\a" "MAMONTOVA\rOleksandra\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.67\r\a" "28\r\a" "23\r\a" "5\r\a"  
[2,] "0.33\r\a" "18\r\a" "27\r\a" "-9\r\a" 
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "25\r\a" "-6\r\a" 
[4,] "0.17\r\a" "17\r\a" "29\r\a" "-12\r\a"
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "15\r\a" "14\r\a" 
[6,] "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "24\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[7,] "0.5\r\a"  "24\r\a" "18\r\a" "6\r\a"  

[[9]]
     [,1]      [,2]                     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "USA\r\a" "NAZLYMOV Tatiana\r\a"   "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "FRA\r\a" "PERRIER Eleonore\r\a"   "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "RUS\r\a" "SHEVELEVA Svetlana\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[4,] "POL\r\a" "OKINE Marta\r\a"        "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[5,] "BEL\r\a" "CORTEYN Saartje\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[6,] "GER\r\a" "KRUEGER Lea\r\a"        "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a"
[7,] "JPN\r\a" "KOBAYASHI Kanae\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]   
[1,] "0.67\r\a" "23\r\a" "18\r\a" "5\r\a" 
[2,] "0.33\r\a" "25\r\a" "26\r\a" "-1\r\a"
[3,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "19\r\a" "10\r\a"
[4,] "0.33\r\a" "18\r\a" "27\r\a" "-9\r\a"
[5,] "0.17\r\a" "20\r\a" "29\r\a" "-9\r\a"
[6,] "0.33\r\a" "17\r\a" "25\r\a" "-8\r\a"
[7,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "17\r\a" "12\r\a"

[[10]]
     [,1]      [,2]                                                    [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
[1,] "GBR\r\a" "CORBY Jessica\r\a"                                     "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[2,] "IND\r\a" "CHADALAVADA\rANANDHA\rSUNDHARARAMAN\rBhavani Devi\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "ALG\r\a" "BOUDIAF Saoussen\r\a"                                  "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "ESP\r\a" "HERNANDEZ Elena\r\a"                                   "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"   
[5,] "GER\r\a" "EIFLER Larissa\r\a"                                    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "CAN\r\a" "GORDON Tamar\r\a"                                      "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[7,] "FRA\r\a" "AIME Amalia\r\a"                                       "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
     [,7]      [,8]      [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "0\r\a"    "7\r\a"  "30\r\a" "-23\r\a"
[2,] "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "16\r\a" "10\r\a" 
[3,] "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "27\r\a" "21\r\a" "6\r\a"  
[4,] "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "26\r\a" "-7\r\a" 
[5,] "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "17\r\a" "12\r\a" 
[6,] "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "17\r\a" "21\r\a" "-4\r\a" 
[7,] "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "0.83\r\a" "25\r\a" "19\r\a" "6\r\a"  

[[11]]
     [,1]      [,2]                             [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] "ALG\r\a" "MOHAMED BELKEBIR\rKaouther\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[2,] "JPN\r\a" "MUKAE Ayaka\r\a"                "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[3,] "FRA\r\a" "POUPINET Anne\r\a"              "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "RUS\r\a" "SMIRNOVA Anna\r\a"              "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "CAN\r\a" "THURGOOD Madison\r\a"           "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "GER\r\a" "KURTH Emily\r\a"                "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"   
[7,] "HUN\r\a" "MISSURAI Palma\r\a"             "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
     [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "D/0\r\a" "0\r\a"    "8\r\a"  "30\r\a" "-22\r\a"
[2,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "26\r\a" "22\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[3,] "V/5\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "15\r\a" "11\r\a" 
[4,] "D/0\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "21\r\a" "22\r\a" "-1\r\a" 
[5,] "V/5\r\a" "0.83\r\a" "25\r\a" "16\r\a" "9\r\a"  
[6,] "D/2\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "27\r\a" "-8\r\a" 
[7,] "\r\a"    "0.5\r\a"  "24\r\a" "17\r\a" "7\r\a"  

[[12]]
     [,1]      [,2]                       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "CAN\r\a" "PONICH Marissa\r\a"       "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "RUS\r\a" "BAZHENOVA\rAnastasia\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "GBR\r\a" "MAXWELL Caitlin\r\a"      "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[4,] "FRA\r\a" "MOUROUX Mathilde\r\a"     "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ITA\r\a" "MORMILE Chiara\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "UKR\r\a" "PROKUDA Olena\r\a"        "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a"
[7,] "ROU\r\a" "MATEI Maria\r\a"          "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]   
[1,] "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "28\r\a" "-9\r\a"
[2,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "22\r\a" "7\r\a" 
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "21\r\a" "26\r\a" "-5\r\a"
[4,] "0.5\r\a"  "26\r\a" "26\r\a" "0\r\a" 
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "29\r\a" "14\r\a" "15\r\a"
[6,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "25\r\a" "-3\r\a"
[7,] "0.33\r\a" "23\r\a" "28\r\a" "-5\r\a"

[[13]]
     [,1]      [,2]                         [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] "FRA\r\a" "DUMAS Marie\r\a"            "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "CRO\r\a" "BALDO Zoe Marie\r\a"        "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "HUN\r\a" "KESZEI Kira\r\a"            "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[4,] "TUR\r\a" "KOSE Fatma Zehra\r\a"       "D/1\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[5,] "POL\r\a" "MATUSZAK Sylwia\r\a"        "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a"
[6,] "ITA\r\a" "ROTILI Claudia\r\a"         "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
[7,] "USA\r\a" "TARTAKOVSKY\rElizabeth\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
     [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "24\r\a" "-3\r\a" 
[2,] "D/3\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "19\r\a" "17\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[3,] "D/4\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "28\r\a" "20\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[4,] "D/3\r\a" "0\r\a"    "13\r\a" "30\r\a" "-17\r\a"
[5,] "V/5\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "24\r\a" "20\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[6,] "D/4\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "20\r\a" "5\r\a"  
[7,] "\r\a"    "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "24\r\a" "1\r\a"  

[[14]]
     [,1]      [,2]                        [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "BEL\r\a" "CORTEYN Jolien\r\a"        "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "USA\r\a" "JENKINS Ryan\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[3,] "ITA\r\a" "BATTISTON Michela\r\a"     "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "GER\r\a" "FUNKE Julika\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "POL\r\a" "ZAWODNIAK\rMalgorzata\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[6,] "FRA\r\a" "LUSINIER Kelly\r\a"        "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a"
[7,] "HUN\r\a" "BATTAI Sugar Katinka\r\a"  "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.67\r\a" "24\r\a" "22\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[2,] "0.5\r\a"  "23\r\a" "22\r\a" "1\r\a"  
[3,] "0.5\r\a"  "26\r\a" "22\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[4,] "1\r\a"    "30\r\a" "13\r\a" "17\r\a" 
[5,] "0.17\r\a" "16\r\a" "28\r\a" "-12\r\a"
[6,] "0.17\r\a" "17\r\a" "27\r\a" "-10\r\a"
[7,] "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "23\r\a" "-2\r\a" 

[[15]]
     [,1]      [,2]                             [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] "FRA\r\a" "RIFKISS Margaux\r\a"            "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "GEO\r\a" "KAKHIANI-MECKLING\rTeodora\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[3,] "VEN\r\a" "RAMOS Crelia\r\a"               "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[4,] "UKR\r\a" "KRAVATSKA Olena\r\a"            "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ITA\r\a" "TARICCO Benedetta\r\a"          "D/2\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a"
[6,] "USA\r\a" "SULLIVAN Siobhan\r\a"           "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
[7,] "ESP\r\a" "GALLARDO Itziar\r\a"            "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
     [,9]      [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "V/5\r\a" "1\r\a"    "30\r\a" "13\r\a" "17\r\a" 
[2,] "V/5\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "22\r\a" "20\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[3,] "V/5\r\a" "0.17\r\a" "16\r\a" "29\r\a" "-13\r\a"
[4,] "V/5\r\a" "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "19\r\a" "6\r\a"  
[5,] "V/5\r\a" "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "24\r\a" "-5\r\a" 
[6,] "D/3\r\a" "0.5\r\a"  "22\r\a" "18\r\a" "4\r\a"  
[7,] "\r\a"    "0.17\r\a" "17\r\a" "28\r\a" "-11\r\a"

[[16]]
     [,1]      [,2]                        [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "ITA\r\a" "ARPINO Giulia\r\a"         "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "FRA\r\a" "TORI Toscane\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[3,] "RUS\r\a" "PODPASKOVA\rEvgenia\r\a"   "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "UKR\r\a" "VORONINA Olena\r\a"        "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[5,] "TUR\r\a" "CAKIR Aylin\r\a"           "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "GBR\r\a" "POTTER Sophia\r\a"         "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a"
[7,] "USA\r\a" "SKARBONKIEWICZ\rMagda\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]   
[1,] "0.5\r\a"  "23\r\a" "18\r\a" "5\r\a" 
[2,] "0.5\r\a"  "25\r\a" "24\r\a" "1\r\a" 
[3,] "1\r\a"    "30\r\a" "15\r\a" "15\r\a"
[4,] "0.33\r\a" "21\r\a" "24\r\a" "-3\r\a"
[5,] "0.5\r\a"  "17\r\a" "24\r\a" "-7\r\a"
[6,] "0.17\r\a" "18\r\a" "27\r\a" "-9\r\a"
[7,] "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "23\r\a" "-2\r\a"

[[17]]
     [,1]      [,2]                    [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "UKR\r\a" "BONDAR Oleksandra\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[2,] "AZE\r\a" "BUNYATOVA Sevil\r\a"   "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "DOM\r\a" "VALENTIN Heyddys\r\a"  "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[4,] "MEX\r\a" "TOLEDO Julieta\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "ROU\r\a" "IACOB Felicia\r\a"     "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "FRA\r\a" "CLAPIER Faustine\r\a"  "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "NED\r\a" "TALBOT Laura\r\a"      "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]     [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "-\r\a"   "0\r\a"  "0\r\a"  "0\r\a"  
[2,] "0.6\r\a" "17\r\a" "18\r\a" "-1\r\a" 
[3,] "0.2\r\a" "14\r\a" "24\r\a" "-10\r\a"
[4,] "0.6\r\a" "23\r\a" "17\r\a" "6\r\a"  
[5,] "0.4\r\a" "19\r\a" "19\r\a" "0\r\a"  
[6,] "1\r\a"   "25\r\a" "11\r\a" "14\r\a" 
[7,] "0.2\r\a" "14\r\a" "23\r\a" "-9\r\a" 

[[18]]
     [,1]      [,2]                      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "ESP\r\a" "VILLEGAS Fabiola\r\a"    "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "NED\r\a" "CLAESSENS Mandy\r\a"     "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "BRA\r\a" "GASPARIN Giulia\r\a"     "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "POL\r\a" "KOZACZUK Malgorzata\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[5,] "HUN\r\a" "SZUCS Luca\r\a"          "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "ITA\r\a" "GARGANO Rebecca\r\a"     "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "UKR\r\a" "PROCHENKO Valeriia\r\a"  "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.17\r\a" "8\r\a"  "29\r\a" "-21\r\a"
[2,] "0.33\r\a" "17\r\a" "23\r\a" "-6\r\a" 
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "16\r\a" "21\r\a" "-5\r\a" 
[4,] "0.67\r\a" "24\r\a" "11\r\a" "13\r\a" 
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "28\r\a" "11\r\a" "17\r\a" 
[6,] "0.83\r\a" "25\r\a" "17\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[7,] "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "25\r\a" "-6\r\a" 

[[19]]
     [,1]      [,2]                     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "FRA\r\a" "LAURENT Clara\r\a"      "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[2,] "AZE\r\a" "KARIMOVA Sabina\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[3,] "HUN\r\a" "BATHORY Kata\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "ESP\r\a" "PEREZ Ainhoa\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[5,] "USA\r\a" "CHAMBERLAIN Maia\r\a"   "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "GER\r\a" "BUERKERT Anna-Lena\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a"
[7,] "ROU\r\a" "LUPU Andreea\r\a"       "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0\r\a"    "19\r\a" "30\r\a" "-11\r\a"
[2,] "0.67\r\a" "25\r\a" "20\r\a" "5\r\a"  
[3,] "0.67\r\a" "27\r\a" "20\r\a" "7\r\a"  
[4,] "0.17\r\a" "16\r\a" "28\r\a" "-12\r\a"
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "28\r\a" "21\r\a" "7\r\a"  
[6,] "0.67\r\a" "23\r\a" "23\r\a" "0\r\a"  
[7,] "0.5\r\a"  "23\r\a" "19\r\a" "4\r\a"  

[[20]]
     [,1]      [,2]                     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "USA\r\a" "GREENBAUM Atara\r\a"    "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[2,] "CZE\r\a" "HANZLIKOVA Klara\r\a"   "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[3,] "KOR\r\a" "JEON Eunhye\r\a"        "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "FRA\r\a" "NOUTCHA Sarah\r\a"      "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[5,] "POL\r\a" "CIESLAR Zuzanna\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[6,] "ROU\r\a" "CHITU Mihaela\r\a"      "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a"
[7,] "ESP\r\a" "PEREZ CUENCA Celia\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.5\r\a"  "21\r\a" "25\r\a" "-4\r\a" 
[2,] "0.17\r\a" "15\r\a" "29\r\a" "-14\r\a"
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "22\r\a" "0\r\a"  
[4,] "0.83\r\a" "26\r\a" "18\r\a" "8\r\a"  
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "27\r\a" "12\r\a" "15\r\a" 
[6,] "0.17\r\a" "13\r\a" "27\r\a" "-14\r\a"
[7,] "0.67\r\a" "24\r\a" "15\r\a" "9\r\a"  

[[21]]
     [,1]      [,2]                      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "VEN\r\a" "VELASQUEZ Jornellys\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/1\r\a"
[2,] "FRA\r\a" "VONGSAVADY Malina\r\a"   "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[3,] "ROU\r\a" "PANTIS Ilinca\r\a"       "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/2\r\a"
[4,] "CHI\r\a" "MORENO Karen\r\a"        "D/2\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/0\r\a"
[5,] "UKR\r\a" "BAKASTOVA Yuliia\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[6,] "POL\r\a" "WATOR Angelika\r\a"      "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/2\r\a"
[7,] "HUN\r\a" "POTZ-NAGY Fanni\r\a"     "V/5\r\a" "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.33\r\a" "19\r\a" "26\r\a" "-7\r\a" 
[2,] "0.67\r\a" "24\r\a" "22\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[3,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "22\r\a" "0\r\a"  
[4,] "0\r\a"    "5\r\a"  "30\r\a" "-25\r\a"
[5,] "0.67\r\a" "27\r\a" "17\r\a" "10\r\a" 
[6,] "0.83\r\a" "27\r\a" "18\r\a" "9\r\a"  
[7,] "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "15\r\a" "11\r\a" 

[[22]]
     [,1]      [,2]                      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     
[1,] "NED\r\a" "BUITENHUIS Marleen\r\a"  "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[2,] "BUL\r\a" "ILIEVA Yoana\r\a"        "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[3,] "HUN\r\a" "LASZLO Luca\r\a"         "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a"
[4,] "AZE\r\a" "BOLSHAKOVA Valeriya\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/0\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a"
[5,] "FRA\r\a" "SUZANNE Coline\r\a"      "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"    "V/5\r\a" "D/3\r\a"
[6,] "GER\r\a" "STRAUB Fanny\r\a"        "D/1\r\a" "D/1\r\a" "D/0\r\a" "D/3\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "\r\a"    "D/1\r\a"
[7,] "ITA\r\a" "PASSARO Eloisa\r\a"      "D/2\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "D/4\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "V/5\r\a" "\r\a"   
     [,10]      [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    
[1,] "0.5\r\a"  "20\r\a" "22\r\a" "-2\r\a" 
[2,] "0.5\r\a"  "25\r\a" "23\r\a" "2\r\a"  
[3,] "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "19\r\a" "7\r\a"  
[4,] "0.33\r\a" "22\r\a" "23\r\a" "-1\r\a" 
[5,] "0.83\r\a" "28\r\a" "19\r\a" "9\r\a"  
[6,] "0\r\a"    "10\r\a" "30\r\a" "-20\r\a"
[7,] "0.67\r\a" "26\r\a" "21\r\a" "5\r\a"
```